# Parsing information from Dentrix desktop application

Tags: java, string, parsing, dentrix

My company wants me to parse information stored in Dentrix software and import it into our database.

I want to extract appointments information (which I believe reside in APPT.DAT file) through java application, but I am having troubles doing this operation. If anyone has any useful hints on that matter please help me.

Regards,
Wa'el

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available for developers now.

You may look into: http://ddp.dentrix.com/

it looks like there's an enrollment fee and some other paperwork, this seems to be read-only for the moment.

It's been promised to change in the future but if you're still interested, take a look!

Comment: I can't find more documentation on the given site. Its just lots of material without gist.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this API: http://twobitsshort.com/
Seems pretty decent.

Comment: is this site still up, I keep getting a 404 error

Comment: do you happen to have a copy of DTXSQL.zip, or know where is get it?

Comment: This site is not working.